# The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is similar to the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose complement is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is my proof, for this propositon correct?

**Proof**:

Let $X$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $Y$ be the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that their complement is finite.
$\implies Y:=\{G \in P(\mathbb{N}): |\mathbb{N}\backslash G |<\aleph_{0}\}$.

Let $A_{K}:=\mathbb{N}\backslash K,\forall K \subset P(\mathbb{N})$ such that $|K|<\aleph_{0}$.

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function such that $f(K):=A_K$.

Let $S,T \in X$ such that $f(S)=f(T)$.

$\implies A_S=A_T \implies \mathbb{N}\backslash S=\mathbb{N}\backslash T \implies S=T$.

$$\begin{align}\implies f \text{ is one-one.}\tag{1}\end{align}$$.

Let $W \in Y$(arbitrary).

Now, $\mathbb{N}\backslash W$, by definition of $Y$, is finite $\implies \mathbb{N}\backslash W \in X$.

$\implies f(\mathbb{N}\backslash W)=A_{(\mathbb{N}\backslash W)}=\mathbb{N} \backslash(\mathbb{N}\backslash W)=W$.

$$\begin{align}\implies f \text{ is onto.}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

$(1),(2)\implies f$ is bijective.

Thus, $X \sim Y$.

*Observation*:
I was thinking about the uncoutablility of $P(\mathbb{N})$. We know that if we partition it into $A$ and $B$, where A contains all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$
and B all the countably infinite ones, then we have $A\sim \mathbb{N}$ and so its the other set which gives $P(\mathbb{N})$ its actual distinction over $\mathbb{N}$, making it an uncountable set of the smallest cardinal ($2^{\aleph_{0}}=\mathfrak{c})$(provided that the Continumm Hypothesis is true.

By this propostion of establishing similarity between $X$ and $Y$, I feel its the countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, whose compliment is countably infinite, that gives $P(\mathbb{N})$ its uncountable nature.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is so far correct but not really necessary. On any base set $X$ the complement operator is bijective, as it is self inverse.

But $Y$ is by definition the image of $X$ under the complement operator. Thus trivially there exists a bijection between these two sets.

The real question is: What do you mean by *sets are similar*? What you’ve proven is that these sets are of equal cardinality. Usually similarity in set theory requires you to have total ordered sets an a bijection that preserves order.

Comment: In here similarity is considered same as two sets having same cardinality.